# Can't copy my object and change values

Tags: java, object

I'm having problems making a copy of an object to use and change values for that copy, instead it changes the values for both of my objects. Code for the object.

```
public class Board {
    private int[][] board;

    public Board() {
        board = new int[9][9];
    }
    public Board(int[][] layout){
        board = layout;
    }

    public int[][] getBoard(){
        return board;
    }
    public int getBoardValue(int y, int x){
        return board[y][x];
    }
    public void insertValue(int v, int y, int x){
        board[y][x] =v;
    }
}
```

And code for the function that I've been trying to get to work

```
public Board copy(Board b) {
    Node node = new Node(b);
    int[][] layout = node.getBoard().getBoard();
    Board temp = new Board(layout);
    temp.insertValue(1,4,5);
    return temp;
}
```

So when I try to insert the value 1 in the new object the old one still changes.

Comment: does it compile? or do you get any other error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public Board(int[][] layout){
  board = layout;
}
```

This make board and layout point at the same adress. Try something like :

```
public Board(int[][] layout){
  this();
  for(int i=0; i<layout.length;i++)
   for(int j=0; j<layout[0].length;j++)
      board[i][j] = layout[i][j];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you assign an array variable to an existing array, you don't get a new array. You get two references to the same array.

For instance:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3};
int[] b = a;
```

`a` and `b` are not two arrays, but two references to the same array. Subsequently altering `a` is the same as altering `b`.

With 2D arrays there is another catch: an array `int[][] x` is actually an array holding a sequence of other arrays. So a naive copy of it (`int[][] y = x.clone()`) would give you two `int[][]` arrays holding shared references to a sequence of `int[]` arrays.

To properly copy a 2D array requires copying the individual 1D arrays inside it.

--

In your case, both your objects hold references to the same array. If you want them to have separate arrays you need to copy the array. You could copy the array in the constructor like this:

```
public Board(int[][] layout) {
    board = new int[layout.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.length; ++i) {
        board[i] = layout[i].clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did not ask this question, but for my learning purposes can you explain this "Both your objects hold references to the same array." for me if you do not mind?

Comment: @KickButtowski `int[][]` is an object type. OP used the object reference of `board` of instance "A" and passed it to instance "B". But since the constructor directly assigns the provided 2d array to the instance variable `board`. That means he hasn't created a copy like he thought, he just *shared* that reference so both instances uses it.

Comment: thank you guys but can anyone dissect the code cuz I cannot see it. I totally get what you see, but I cannot make connection between what you guys said and the code snippet

Comment: @khelwood clone does the shallow copying in object as far as I know . is not good to use deep copying? like use Arrays.copyOf()

Comment: @KickButtowski `Arrays.copyOf` is slower and no deeper than using `clone()` on an array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to copy the `layout` array as well.

```
public Board copy(Board b) {
    Node node = new Node(b);
    int[][] oldLayout = node.getBoard().getBoard();
    int[][] newLayout = new int[9][9];
    for(int i=0; i<newLayout.length; i++) {
        newLayout[i] = Arrays.copyOf(oldLayout[i], oldLayout[i].length);
    }
    Board temp = new Board(newLayout);
    temp.insertValue(1,4,5);
    return temp;
}
```